# NextAuth not returning custom scopes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, oauth-2.0, next-auth

I have NextJS project that's using NextAuth. It works fine when I use default scopes. However my project requires additional claims and you can see the supported scopes [here](https://auth.ncats.nih.gov/_api/v2/auth/ls/.well-known/openid-configuration).

```
  "scopes_supported": [
    "openid",
    "offline_access",
    "iss",
    "address",
    "email",
    "phone",
    "profile",
    "external_groups",
    "access_roles",
    "tenant",
    "groups",
    "identity_provider",
    "linked_identity",
    "amr",
    "custom_claims",
    "provider_claims"
  ],
```

I use below config to fetch those custom claims

```
authorization: { params: { scope: 'openid profile email external_groups access_roles groups custom_claims provider_claims' } },
```

However I do not see any custom claims and default claims are being returned. You can reproduce the error with code: https://github.com/pavankjadda/next-auth-demo

Answer (score 0):

So that issue is NextAuth not returning user data. I had to overwrite the userInfo end point by passing `access_token` to get the required data

```
userinfo: {
    url: 'https://auth.ncats.nih.gov/_api/v2/auth/NCI-CCR-TEST/me',
    async request(context) {
    return await context.client.userinfo(context.tokens?.access_token ?? '');
  },
},
```

Note: Make sure to remove unnecessary scopes from `authorization` as it will increase cookie that being sent to Auth server

```
authorization: { params: { scope: 'openid profile email' } },
```